# How to remove an item from a custom Walker_Nav_Menu

Tags: categories, menus, walker, exclude

I have a custom menu on a wordpress + woocommerce site using the Walker_Nav_Menu class. When hiding posts (products) from the site those posts and category are still included in the custom menu. 
I would like to know how to remove either the specific product posts from this menu, for e.g. post ID = 6927 - or to remove the category (and the products therein) from this menu, for e.g. category ID = 41.The category I want to hide is "End of range" in this image:

[image: screengrab of custom menu]

I have tried many solutions over the past 2 days without success:

1)

```
function wpse31748_exclude_menu_items( $items, $menu, $args ) {
    // Iterate over the items to search and destroy
    foreach ( $items as $key => $item ) {
        if ( $item->object_id == 6927 ) unset( $items[$key] );
    }

    return $items;
}

add_filter( 'wp_get_nav_menu_items', 'wpse31748_exclude_menu_items', null, 3 );
```

and different variations of above.

I'm not sure if I'm completely off track but I thought updating the file template-parts/modules/module-category-menu.php to exclude the category may work, here is the contents of that file:

```
<?php
$orderby = 'date';
$order = 'desc';
$hide_empty = true ;
$cat_args = array(
  'orderby'    => $orderby,
  'order'      => $order,
  'hide_empty' => $hide_empty,

);

$product_categories = get_terms( 'product_cat', $cat_args );
if( !empty($product_categories)) : 
  ?>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 sec-menu">
      <ul class=" nav nav-justified" id="sec-menu">
        <?php
        foreach ($product_categories as $key => $category):
          ?>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <h2>
            <a class="nav-link collapsed top-menu" href="#cat<?php echo $category->term_id; ?>" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#cat<?php echo $category->term_id; ?>">  
             <?php echo $category->name; ?>

           </a>
            </h2>     
           <?php
           $args = array(
            'posts_per_page' => '-1',
            'post_type' => 'product',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'orderby'    => 'date',
            'order'      => 'asc',
            'tax_query' => array(
              array(
                'taxonomy'  => 'product_cat',
                'terms'     => array($category->term_id),
                'operator'   => 'IN'
              ),
            )
          );
           $products = new WP_Query($args);
           if($products->have_posts()):
             ?>
             <div class="collapse sub-menu" id="cat<?php echo $category->term_id; ?>" aria-expanded="false" data-parent="#sec-menu">
              <ul class="flex-column nav">
                <?php
                while($products->have_posts()):
                  $products->the_post();
                  ?>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link sub-link" href="<?php the_permalink();?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
                      <span><?php the_title(); ?></span>                      
                    </a>
                  </li>
                  <?php
                endwhile;
                wp_reset_query();
                ?>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <?php
          endif;
          ?>
        </li>
        <?php
      endforeach;
      ?>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<?php
endif; 
?>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**
Here is the Walker_Nav_Menu class from the functions.php file:

```
class Custom_Foundation_Nav_Menu extends Walker_Nav_Menu

 {


    private $curItem;

    function display_element($element, &$children_elements, $max_depth, $depth = 0, $args, &$output)
    {

        $element->hasChildren = isset($children_elements[$element->ID]) && !empty($children_elements[$element->ID]);
        return parent::display_element($element, $children_elements, $max_depth, $depth, $args, $output);

    }

    function start_el(&$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0)
    {

        global $wp_query;

        $new_class = array();

        $this->curItem = $item;

        $indent = ($depth) ? str_repeat("\t", $depth) : '';

        $class_names = $value = '';

        $classes = empty($item->classes) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;
        $new_class[] = 'nav-item';
        if (in_array('current-menu-item', $classes) || in_array('current-menu-ancestor', $classes)) {
            $new_class[] = 'active';
        }
        if ($item->hasChildren) {
            $add_sub_class = 'nav-link collapsed';
        } else {
            $add_sub_class = 'nav-link';
        }

        if ($depth > 0) {
            $add_sub_class .= ' sub-link ';
        }



        $new_class = implode(' ', $new_class);
        // echo $new_class;
        $class_names = join(' ', apply_filters('nav_menu_css_class', array_filter($classes), $item));
        $class_names = ' class="' . $new_class . ' ' . $class_names . '"';
        $class_names = trim($class_names);


        $output .= $indent . '<li id="menu-item-' . $item->ID . '" ' . $value . $class_names . '>';
        $attributes = !empty($item->attr_title) ? ' title="' . esc_attr($item->attr_title) . '" ' : '';
        if ($item->hasChildren && !is_page(6927)) {
            $attributes .= ' href="#submenu' . $item->ID . '" ';
            $attributes .= ' data-toggle="collapse" ';
            $attributes .= ' data-target="#submenu' . $item->ID . '" ';
        } else {
            $attributes .= !empty($item->url) ? ' href="' . esc_attr($item->url) . '" ' : '';
        }
        $attributes .= !empty($add_sub_class) ? ' class="' . $add_sub_class . '" ' : '';

        $item_output = $args->before;
        $item_output .= '<a' . $attributes . ' ><span data-hover="' . $args->link_before . apply_filters('the_title', $item->title, $item->ID) . '">';

        $item_output .= $args->link_before . apply_filters('the_title', $item->title, $item->ID);
        $item_output .= '</span></a>';
        $item_output .= $args->after;

        $output .= apply_filters('walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args);
    }

    function start_lvl(&$output, $depth = 0, $args = array())

    {
        global $wp_query;

        $thisItem = $this->curItem;
        $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
        $output .= "\n$indent<div class='collapse' id='submenu$thisItem->ID' aria-expanded='false'><ul id='submenu-$thisItem->ID' class='flex-column nav sub-nav'>\n";
    }

}
```

Comment: are you using wp_nav_menu() to output the menu? did you supply any $args? if so, what is the $args? You have mentioned about the Walker_Nav_Menu but there seems no related code for using this other than the filter.

Comment: @simongcc I've edited my question to add in the code for the Walker_Nav_Menu from the functions.php file.

Comment: I have shared some way for you to try. If you haven't tried these methods, you may give it a try first. Because they are too long as a comment. So I post it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

I am still not sure how you call the menu or what $args you supply for the menu. But could suggest you some way to figure it out.

first test: return an empty array, if menu becomes empty, the filter is running,

if not, then your filter is not running and need to find another way

```
function wpse31748_exclude_menu_items( $items, $menu, $args ) {
    return [];
}
add_filter( 'wp_get_nav_menu_items', 'wpse31748_exclude_menu_items', null, 3 );
```

---

assume the filter is running, then probably your test logic have problem

```
function wpse31748_exclude_menu_items( $items, $menu, $args ) {

    // Iterate over the items to search and destroy
    $found_key = null;
    foreach ( $items as $key => $item ) {
        if ( $item->object_id == 6927 ) {
          // unset( $items[$key] ); // unset a iterating array is not a good idea and may lead to bug sometimes
          $found_key = $key; // handle it later.
        }
    }

    var_dump($found_key); // make sure you find something

    var_dump($items); // to compare before and after removal if it found something
    unset( $items[$found_key] );
    var_dump($items);

    return $items;
}

add_filter( 'wp_get_nav_menu_items', 'wpse31748_exclude_menu_items', null, 3 );
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I will try this out

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved this by editing the $cat_args array to exclude the category IDs I don't want shown in any menu (in below e.g. 34 is the category ID) - the file in my case was in a 'modules' folder:

```
<?php
$orderby = 'date';
$order = 'desc';
$hide_empty = true ;
$cat_args = array(
  'orderby'    => $orderby,
  'order'      => $order,
  'hide_empty' => $hide_empty,
  'exclude' => '34',
);
```

Category is removed from the menu but the specific posts can still be accessed and linked to with direct linking.